# POSTing properly to this API

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I'm trying to POST to this [API](https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger#!/Authentication/post_login). Unfortunately, I'm not able to pass the authentication.

```
$apiKey = 'mykey';
$username = 'myuid';
$userKey = 'myuserkey';
$url = 'https://api.thetvdb.com/login?';
$LoginQuery = array('apikey' => $apiKey,
                    'userkey' => $userKey,
                    'username' => $username
                    );
$postfields = json_encode($LoginQuery);
$urlquery = $url . json_encode($LoginQuery);
p_print("URL: " . $urlquery);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($json);
```

Response:

```
{
  "Error": "Bad Content-Type or charset, expected 'application/json'"
}
```

Isnt what I'm posting json? How am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` to be `application/json`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```